# Net use Access is denied Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, сеть, cmd, windows-10, windows-server-2016

Я пытаюсь подключиться к удаленному сетевому серверу(Windows Server 2016):

```
net use e: \\10.0.1.10\c$ password /user:login
```

Получаю ошибку:

> System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.

```
net use e: \\10.0.1.10\f$ password /user:localhost@login
```

> System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.

Что я проверил:

- Аккаунт находится в группе администраторы
- Login и password правильные
- Через "Удаленный рабочий стол" подключение есть
- Диск С:\ присутствует на удаленной машине
- Диск Е:\ отсутствует на моей машине
- Через login: Administrator net use работает

Кто то знает в чем проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте указать домен, если его нет, тогда локалхост `/user:127.0.0.1\login`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После установки всех последних обновлений и перезагрузки windows-2016 `net use` заработал